# Must be an updateable query error in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I believe the below query would work in any other database except for Access.  I get the 'Must be an updateable query' error.  How should I rework this?  (Typically I would put an INNER JOIN in the UPDATE part of the query, but I don't think I can in this instance).

```
UPDATE MASTER_DATA
    SET VS_ID = (SELECT VS_ID FROM MASTER_VS_AND_BUILDING WHERE VALUE_STREAM = 'TERMINAL')
WHERE MATERIAL_NUMBER = 'Z12345678'
```

Comment: Please describe schema of both tables. In fact are both tables or one of them a query? Is *VS_ID* a primary key? Is this a one-to-one, one-to-many row update?

Comment: The MASTER_VS_AND_BUILDING holds the primary key for VS_ID.  It has a one-to-many relationship with MASTER_DATA.  I need to get the VS_ID based on the VALUE_STREAM and place the VS_ID in the MASTER_DATA table.

Comment: Please show example data of both tables to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe DLookup():

```
UPDATE MASTER_DATA
    SET VS_ID = DLookup("VS_ID", "MASTER_VS_AND_BUILDING", "VALUE_STREAM = 'TERMINAL'")
WHERE MATERIAL_NUMBER = 'Z12345678'
```